# Nested View in Angular UI router not loading content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular js app that's compiled via browserify. Everything is function with the state provider except for my nested state view.

Inside of my first included template:

```
<div class="carosel">
<div ui-view="ui-view" class="carosel_viewer"></div>
<div class="carosel_control">
    <ul>
       <li>Highlights</li>
       <li>Social</li>
       <li>Locations</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Inside of my state router I have:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        .state('home.social', {
            url: '/social',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.first.html'
        });
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

})
```

I don't get any errors but the content doesn't show up inside of the carosel_viewer. I initially started with the standard $routeProvider and an ng-include which worked, so it would seem that locations and paths are correct. I've since decided that I want each stage of the 'carosel' (yes, it's not spelled correctly) to be mapped to a unique path for sharing, etc. If someone has a better suggestion for that, I am happy to entertain best practices, too. I'm a bit of a angular noob.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. UI Router is best to handle such scenarios.

The only issue in your code is that when you want to open some view in a certain named block you have to explicitly specify the name of the block in which the view should get attached.

Your code should be modified as below:

```
<div ui-view="carosel_viewer" class="carosel_viewer"></div>

views: {
  'carosel_viewer': {
   'url': 'home',
   'templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',

  },
}
```

Not tested though the above but something similar should work for you.
You can read more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My only question is that I thought the whole idea of a nested view was the ability to tap into the parent.child view notation to update a nested ui-view? For example, in this scenario at egghead.

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router

Comment: You can do that also and it can be used just for normal views. If you want to attach a template to certain element just initialise that element with blank 'ui-view' attribute. I hope I understood what you wanted to ask :)

Comment: I'm giving you the points since you're suggestion led me to he right path. For whatever reason, there is some kind of bug that wasn't seeing the nested ui-view - but when I gave it an empty value of ="" then it worked. Not sure why, but - it works now. Thanks!

Comment: should mention that it could be my fault since I am technically introducing extra complexity to the solution by first compiling jade templates attempting to add the angular features in through their parameters. :)

Comment: I am glad my comment helped you :) Earning points is not the motive, here to help other users out of little knowledge that I have. Cos this site and users here have helped me a lot when I was stuck in issues. Its time give back. Thanks for the points though.